# Why php scripts must be saved in www folder?

Tags: php, html, localhost

I just started learning PHP and I'm confusing about 2 questions.

1. Why php scripts must be saved within a folder called "www".
   [image]
2. I have a php projects where there are few sub-pages that I want to link from the index.php. For example, I want navigate to the category4_4.php from index.php via an anchor tag.

[image]

In index.php, I have a navigation bar that looks like:
[image]

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/categories/category4_4/category4_4.php" target="_blank">Contact</a>
</li>
```

The error I got when I clicked on the link:

[image]

Did I wrongly declare my file path? From what I know, starting with a backslash "/" always refers to the root folder which is the 'frontend-cms-template' in this case.

Comment: 1. They don't have to _in general_, this is just the directory that Wamp has specified as _document root_.

Comment: 2. What is the URL that you used to access the `index.php` in the first place?

Comment: The files are in www because the webserver says they should be in www. You can put them anywhere on your drive as long as wamp knows where they should be. As for the 404, your directory looks weird in your screenshot. Normally subdirectories would be listed inside of the parent directory and yours is not. I'm wondering if the naming got messed up somehow, such as naming the directory with a slash

Comment: @CBroe The url that I used to access my index.php is "http://localhost/frontend-cms-template".

Comment: @aynber Yea. Maybe the way I organize the directory is really bad. Still figuring out the reason why I can't link to the category4_4.php..

Comment: `/` in URLs refers to the domain root, which in your case is `http://localhost/`. You still need to include the name of the folder below the root, that your files are actually in. _"[...] the root folder which is the 'frontend-cms-template' in this case."_ - no, it isn't, otherwise you would have accessed your index.php via just `http://localhost/` in the first place.

Comment: If the name of your directories are bad (such as the directory named "categories/category4_4" instead of a directory of category4_4 inside of categories) then your webserver is going to have problems accessing it

Comment: @CBroe Yea. The link is able to work right now. Thanks for helping!!

Comment: @aynber Okay. I will re-organize the structure of the directory. Thanks for telling!!

Comment: If you use the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) with a router (which I recommend), you usually only keep one single php file under your www-root (index.php) and all other files outside of the www-root. That index.php file then includes the files it needs to server that request.

Comment: fyi: "/" is a slash, "\" is a backslash

Answer (score 0):

> Did I wrongly declare my file path? From what I know, starting with a
> backslash "/" always refers to the root folder which is the
> 'frontend-cms-template' in this case.

No, to PHP "root" is `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, which is usually `https://localhost` in the browser. To see which folder document root is in relation to your file system, display the predefined variable `$_SERVER` like so:

`echo($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

In your case it's probably `C:\wamp64\www`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ./ for one back directory and 2nd back use ../

Contact